# Does SELECT COUNT(*) work with MySQLi prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm working on a test page and am using MySQLi prepared statements in my queries after reading they make my code safe from SQL injection. I have been successful with prepared statements so far with retrieving data from my DB, that all works great.

What I want to do now is count the number of galleries within a project using SELECT COUNT(*). That's it.

Without using a prepared statement, my old query looked like this:

```
// count number of galleries per project
$conn = dbConnect('query');
$galNumb = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pj_galleries WHERE project = {$pjInfo['pj_id']}";
$gNumb = $conn->query($galNumb);
$row = $gNumb->fetch_row();
$galTotal = $row[0];
```

But for all my reading and searching the internet, I can not find out the proper way to write this as a prepared statement.

Comment: a moderator deleted my answer for some reason. Instead of building the MySQLi stuff yourself, you could also opt for using a standard library, for example: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13352/mysqli-db-library-quality-security-review

Comment: Jacco...I noticed. I appreciate your help, you are a very helpful person, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be over-thinking things, because it's not different than any other prepared statement:

```
$conn = new mysqli;
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pj_galleries WHERE project = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $pjInfo['pj_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_row();
$galTotal = $row[0];
```

Comment: I just tried that on my page and I got an error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::bind_param() in /path/file.php on line 26 - what did I miss?

Comment: @EP fantastic! I'll give it a whirl tomorrow. This has absolutely crushed my brain today. Thank you and everyone here for your help! Will let you know how it goes tomorrow.

Comment: @EP I kept getting errors then I changed `($query)` to `($galNumb)` and got it to work. Am fiddling with it now, though it should give the number 3, it's still only saying 1. Will let you know what I find out.

Comment: Please don't be sorry! You've helped me more than you know.

Comment: @EP - What I can't understand is why, when there are 3 galleries in this project, why the result is 1. If you are available for chat I can elaborate.

Comment: @EP - Okay, after doing some number changing in the DB, the result returns 1 no matter which numbers are in the column. Weird.

Comment: $stmt->execute() never returns resultset,it returns true or false based on how the execution went, if you want count(\*) you'll have to add the following lines of code
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($totalRows);
$stmt->fetch();
you will find the value of count(\*) in $totalRows

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it should work just fine.

However, keep in mind that doing a `COUNT(primary_key)` usually gives better performance.

So your above query would look like

```
// first, setup your DB-connection
$mysqli = new mysqli('example.com', 'user', '********', 'database');

// Preparing the statement
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pj_galleries WHERE project = ?');

// binding the parameters
$stmt->bind_param('i', $pjInfo['pj_id']); // 'i' signals an integer

// Executing the query
if ( ! $stmt->execute()) {
    trigger_error('The query execution failed; MySQL said ('.$stmt->errno.') '.$stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

// fetching the results
$col1 = null;
$stmt->bind_result($col1); // you can bind multiple colums in one function call
while ($stmt->fetch()) { // for this query, there will only be one row, but it makes for a more complete example
    echo "counted {$col1} records\n";
}

$stmt->close(); // explicitly closing your statements is good practice
```

For a better and more complete explanation, please take a look at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php (examples should get you up to speed).

Also keep in mind that you can execute a prepared statement multiple times, if needed. You could also bind new parameters before re-executing your query.

Comment: Jacco, that's not what I am asking. I want to know how to write the above code AS a prepared statement.

Comment: Thank you for the concise and helpful answer. Um...what variable do I use to echo the result?

Comment: Jacco, what I want is to simply count the number of galleries for a given project, say Project 1 has 3 galleries. All I want the query to do is return the number, in this case, 3.

Comment: I've added some more code comments, I hope this clears it up. I would advice rewriting your query as `SELECT COUNT(pj_galleries_id) FROM pj_galleries WHERE project = ?` where I assume `pj_galleries_id` is the primary key for the `pj_galleries` table.

Comment: Jacco, but the data I want to count is not in the primary key.The table pj_galleries holds info for all of the individual projects and their associated galleries.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to count all records belonging to a certain project_id. By counting the primary key, you should get an identical result to `COUNT(*)`; it is the `WHERE` clause that tells MySQL which rows to count. (try it out, experimenting is the best method to progress).